# Java KeyListener Stops Working

Tags: java, swing, canvas, keylistener

**- = UPDATE = -**

It turns out the issue was not with Java but with my Apple keyboard. Holding down a letter key brings up a menu that breaks my Java programs. By disabling that menu popup, my KeyListener and my Key Bindings both work as they should. Thank you all for your answers.

**Question**

I have searched on Google and on StackOverflow for an answer to my question, but to no avail. All of the questions that I've found have the main class extending JComponent, JFrame, JPanel, etc., and not Canvas.

Now for my question:

I am having trouble getting my Java KeyListener to cooperate while my program runs. When I start my program, everything works as usual. However, as I start pressing keys and moving things around (with said keys), the program begins to delay and take more time for the key presses to register. All of a sudden, they KeyListener breaks altogether and I get no input (even a System.out.println statement in the keyPressed method shows no activity). I have three classes that have to do with my KeyListener in any way.

If it helps, the goal of this program is to use BufferedImage class to plot points from different mathematical functions, like a sine wave. I have commented the best I can without being Super-Comment-Man, but I can clarify on the purpose of any code to the best of my ability.

First, my Screen class (draws stuff on the JFrame with a BufferStrategy):

```
package com.elek.waves.graphics;

import java.awt.Canvas;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.image.BufferStrategy;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.awt.image.DataBufferInt;

import javax.swing.JFrame;

import com.elek.waves.graphics.math.Controller;
import com.elek.waves.graphics.math.Graph;
import com.elek.waves.input.Keyboard;

/**
 * The engine of the entire Waves project. Processes the BufferedImage and puts the JFrame
 * on the screen. Uses other classes to calculate where to put pixels (what color each pixel
 * in the array should be) and get keyboard input.
 * 
 * @author my name
 * @version 1.0
 */
public class Screen extends Canvas {
    /**
     * Holds some *important* number that makes Java happy.
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    /**
     * Constant (and static) dimensions of the window.
     */
    public static final int WIDTH = 800, HEIGHT = 800;

    /**
     * Frame that will contain the BufferedImage and all its glory.
     */
    private JFrame frame;

    /**
     * BufferedImage processes the pixel array and translates it into fancy screen magic.
     */
    private BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(WIDTH, HEIGHT, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);

    /**
     * Holds color data for each pixel on the screen. Each pixel has an integer value equivalent
     * to the hexadecimal RGB value for whatever color this pixel is supposed to be.
     */
    private int[] pixels = ((DataBufferInt)image.getRaster().getDataBuffer()).getData();

    /**
     * Graph object to draw the lines on.
     */
    private Graph graph;

    /**
     * Controller object to control the graph.
     */
    private Controller controller;

    /**
     * Keybaord object to use as a key-listener.
     */
    private Keyboard key;

    /* -- Constructor -- */

    /**
     * Creates a new Screen object. Initializes the JFrame object.
     */
    public Screen() {
        frame = new JFrame("Magic!");

        graph = new Graph(pixels);
        key = new Keyboard();

        controller = new Controller(key, graph);

        addKeyListener(key);
    }

    /* -- Methods -- */

    /**
     * Called once and only once by the main method. Repeatedly calls the update and render methods
     * until the program stops running.
     */
    private void start() {
        this.requestFocus();
        this.requestFocusInWindow();

        while (true) {
            update();
            render();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Called by the start method repeatedly. First, clears the screen of the previous image in
     * order to prevent ghost-imaging or blurring. Then, updates the pixel array to whatever it
     * needs to be for the next iteration of the render method.
     */
    private void update() {
        // Update the keyboard input
        key.update();

        // Update the controller
        controller.update();

        // Clean up the screen and then graph the line
        clearScreen();
        graph.drawWave();
    }

    /**
     * Called by the start method repeatedly. Draws the pixel array onto the JFrame using the
     * BufferedImage magic.
     */
    private void render() {
        // Initialize buffer strategies
        BufferStrategy bs = getBufferStrategy();

        if (bs == null) {
            createBufferStrategy(2);
            return;
        }

        // Physically update the actual pixels on the image
        Graphics g = (Graphics2D) bs.getDrawGraphics();
        g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight(), null);
        g.dispose();
        bs.show();
    }

    /**
     * Clears the screen by setting every pixel in the pixel array to black. Used to prevent
     * ghost-images or blurring.
     */
    public void clearScreen() {
        for (int i = 0; i < pixels.length; i++)
            pixels[i] = 0;
    }

    /**
     * Main method to run the program. Creates a Screen object with a BufferedImage to display
     * pixels however the other classes decide to. All this does is set up the JFrame with the
     * proper parameters and properties to get it up and running.
     * 
     * @param   args    A String array of random arguments that Java requires or it gets fussy
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Create Screen object
        Screen screen = new Screen();

        screen.frame.add(screen);
        screen.frame.pack();
        screen.frame.setSize(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
        screen.frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        screen.frame.setResizable(false);
        screen.frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        screen.frame.setVisible(true);

        screen.start();
    }
}
```

Second, my Keyboard class (KeyListener that breaks):

```
package com.elek.waves.input;

import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;

/**
 * Gets the user's key strokes and determines which keys are down at a given time.
 * 
 * @author my name
 * @version 1.0
 */
public class Keyboard implements KeyListener {
    /**
     * Holds the state of 120 keys (true if they're down, false if they're not).
     */
    private boolean[] keys = new boolean[120];

    /**
     * Holds the state of the "useful" keys (true if down, false if not).
     */
    public boolean w, a, s, d, up, down, left, right;

    /**
     * Determines if the "useful" keys are down or not. Sets the variables to true if they're down and
     * false if they're up.
     */
    public void update() {
        w = keys[KeyEvent.VK_W];
        a = keys[KeyEvent.VK_A];
        s = keys[KeyEvent.VK_S];
        d = keys[KeyEvent.VK_D];

        up = keys[KeyEvent.VK_UP];
        down = keys[KeyEvent.VK_DOWN];
        left = keys[KeyEvent.VK_LEFT];
        right = keys[KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT];
    }

    /**
     * Changes the state of the pressed key's corresponding boolean in the array to true.
     */
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        keys[e.getKeyCode()] = true;
    }

    /**
     * Changes the state of the pressed key's corresponding boolean in the array to false.
     */
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
        keys[e.getKeyCode()] = false;
    }

    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
    }
}
```

Third, my Controller class (uses the KeyListener to control the program):

```
package com.elek.waves.graphics.math;

import com.elek.waves.input.Keyboard;

/**
 * Controls the graph's transformation properties (stretching and shifting). Directly changes the
 * transformation variables in the Graph class to achieve this.
 * 
 * @author my name
 * @version 1.0
 */
public class Controller {
    /**
     * Keyboard object to get the user's key-inputs.
     */
    private Keyboard input;

    /**
     * Graph object that this Controller will control.
     */
    private Graph graph;

    /* -- Constructor -- */

    /**
     * Create a new Controller object with the specific keyboard input parameter. 
     * <pre>Sets the starting parameters as the following:
     * Vertical Scale: 1
     * Horizontal Scale: 1
     * Vertical Shift = 0
     * Horizontal Shift = 0</pre>
     * 
     * @param   input   The Keybaord object from which the controller will get input
     */
    public Controller(Keyboard input, Graph parent) {
        // Initialize keybaord input and graph parent
        this.input = input;
        graph = parent;

        // Initialize transformation variables
        graph.vScale = 50;
        graph.hScale = 0.05;
        graph.vShift = 0;
        graph.hShift = 0;
    }

    /* -- Methods -- */

    /**
     * Updates the shifting of the graph (moving around) and the scaling of the graph (stretching)
     * from the keyboard input. <strong>WASD</strong> keys control shifting, and <strong>up, down, 
     * left, and right</strong> keys control stretching.
     */
    public void update() {
        // Update shifting
        if (input.w)        graph.vShift += 0.5;
        if (input.s)        graph.vShift -= 0.5;
        if (input.a)        graph.hShift -= 0.04;
        if (input.d)        graph.hShift += 0.04;

        // Update scaling
        if (input.up)       graph.vScale += 0.5;
        if (input.down)     graph.vScale -= 0.5;
        if (input.left)     graph.hScale += 0.0001;
        if (input.right)    graph.hScale -= 0.0001;
    }
}
```

I have found several helpful people saying to use KeyBindings as opposed to a KeyListener. However, I have used a KeyListener successfully in the past, and I'd like to get it to work again if possible. If KeyBindings are absolutely necessary, I supposed I can make the switch, but I'd prefer if that didn't have to be the case.

Thank you all in advance!

Comment: You should probably base your program on the tutorial examples you found. Extending Canvas seems like a really poor idea. As is running everything in a `while True` look instead of responding to events.

Comment: @pvg [BufferStrategy and BufferCapabilities](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/fullscreen/bufferstrategy.html)

Comment: @MadProgrammer ah. it's confusing because it also makes it look like a polling loop instead of a render loop.

Comment: @pvg It's an example of active painting, basically it allows you to take control of the paint process for the component, instead of relying on the normal passive painting process supplied by Swing

Comment: @MadProgrammer yeah I got that, talking about something else. Not important.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Canvas` will suffer the same issues that all the other components suffer from, loss of keyboard focus, this is why we generally don't recommend `KeyListener`.

First you need to make the `Canvas` focusable, see [`Canvas#setFocusable`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#setFocusable-boolean-)

The next, more difficult issue, is requesting keyboard focus, you can use [`Canvas#requestFocusInWindow`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#requestFocusInWindow--) but any component which requires keyboard focus will steal it.

Depending on what you are doing, you might be able to simply place the call in the update loop, but you need to be aware that if you want to ask input from the user, within the same window, you will have issues (with the canvas stealing the focus)

## Update

I had some issues with index of bounds due to the use of an array in the keyboard controller, which I switched over to `Set` instead...

```
public class Keyboard implements KeyListener {

    /**
     * Holds the state of 120 keys (true if they're down, false if they're
     * not).
     */
```

//        private boolean[] keys = new boolean[120];

```
    /**
     * Holds the state of the "useful" keys (true if down, false if not).
     */
    private Set<Integer> keys;

    /**
     * Determines if the "useful" keys are down or not. Sets the variables
     * to true if they're down and false if they're up.
     */
    public void update() {
        
        keys = new HashSet<>(8);
    }
    
    public boolean isKeyPressed(int key) {
        return keys.contains(key);
    }
    
    public boolean isWPressed() {
        return isKeyPressed(KeyEvent.VK_W);
    }
    
    public boolean isAPressed() {
        return isKeyPressed(KeyEvent.VK_A);
    }
    
    public boolean isSPressed() {
        return isKeyPressed(KeyEvent.VK_S);
    }
    
    public boolean isDPressed() {
        return isKeyPressed(KeyEvent.VK_D);
    }

    public boolean isUpPressed() {
        return isKeyPressed(KeyEvent.VK_UP);
    }
    
    public boolean isDownPressed() {
        return isKeyPressed(KeyEvent.VK_DOWN);
    }
    
    public boolean isLeftPressed() {
        return isKeyPressed(KeyEvent.VK_LEFT);
    }
    
    public boolean isRightPressed() {
        return isKeyPressed(KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT);
    }
    /**
     * Changes the state of the pressed key's corresponding boolean in the
     * array to true.
     */
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        System.out.println("Pressed = " + e.getKeyCode());
        keys.add(e.getKeyCode());
    }

    /**
     * Changes the state of the pressed key's corresponding boolean in the
     * array to false.
     */
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
        System.out.println("Released = " + e.getKeyCode());
        keys.remove(e.getKeyCode());
    }

    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
    }
}
```

I also added a small delay into the render loop so you're not chocking the system

```
private void start() {
    setFocusable(true);
    while (true) {
        this.requestFocusInWindow();
        update();
        render();
        try {
            Thread.sleep(16);
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I appreciate your quick answer. I have no other components besides the `JFrame`, so there should be no issue with the focus being "stolen" by anything else. Once I make the `Canvas` focusable, will my existing `this.requestFocus()` and `this.requestFocusInWindow()` code in the `start()` method do the trick, or would you advise I move them elsewhere for better efficiency or robustness?

Comment: Because the time it takes to get the actually window on screen can very, I'd be placing the request for focus inside the update loop just to make sure it's always on the canvas. I'd also call `start` from inside your own `Thread`, to ensure you're not blocking the normal event dispatching thread

Comment: I added a `Thread` and put `this.setFocusable(true)`, `this.requestFocus()`, and `this.requestFocusInWindow()` inside of the loop that calls the `update()` method. However, the KeyListener still breaks quickly after I press a letter key, like the "W" key. Is there a way to fix that, or should I just go with key binding at this point?

Comment: Apart from missing the Graph class, the only issue I have is when I press a key outside the range of your array, like "x"

Comment: Could the fact that I am running on a macOS system contribute to my problem? I merely oscillated between the "A" and "D" keys and the entire GUI froze up and the KeyListener stopped receiving inputs.

Comment: @elektrikpulse61 That could be an issue, I had an issue (in particular with `A`) not registering as been pressed, but did trigger the release event

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.KeyAdapter;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;

public class Main {


    public static void main(String[] argv) throws Exception {

        JTextField textField = new JTextField();

        textField.addKeyListener(new MKeyListener());

        JFrame jframe = new JFrame();
        jframe.add(textField);

        jframe.setSize(700, 700);

        jframe.setVisible(true);

    }
}
class MKeyListener extends KeyAdapter {

    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent event) {
        System.out.println(event.getKeyCode)
        if(event.getKeyCode() = \\key code here\\){
            System.out.println("True")
            }else{System.out.println("False")
```

Allthough this was ran in `package java` but there shouldnt be anything wrong with it