# Why does my KeyPressed event randomly stop working?

Tags: java, swing, keylistener, keyevent

I am new to Java, and am trying to learn GUI basics by making a simple application.
My application is just a simple button that, when clicked, changes its name to the number of times it has been clicked.

I want to be able to reset the counter/button name when the user presses the "r" key, but for some reason it only works before the button has been clicked.
After the counter goes over zero, the key press is no longer detected.

I have tried everything I can find on the internet, including:

- Multiple different Key Listeners
- `frame.setFocusable(true);`
- Youtube tutorials
- Existing Stack Overflow posts (none seem to match this problem)
- Debugging (not showing any errors)

I can't figure out what's going on. If someone could help, it would be MUCH appreciated. My code is below. (I don't know which part of it is causing the problem, so I can't make it too short or I might crop out something important. It's only 90 lines.)

```
import java.awt.AWTException;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class Clicker implements ActionListener {
    JMenu m1;
    JMenuItem m11;
    JMenuItem m22;
    JButton button;
    int counter = 0;
    
    public Clicker() throws AWTException {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Click Counter");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(300,300);
        
        JMenuBar mb = new JMenuBar();
        JMenu m1 = new JMenu("File");
        mb.add(m1);
        m11 = new JMenuItem("Reset");
        m22= new JMenuItem("Quit");
        m1.add(m11);
        m1.add(m22);
        button = new JButton("Click");

        frame.getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.CENTER, button);
        frame.getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.NORTH, mb);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setFocusable(true);
        
        m22.setToolTipText("⌘Q");
        m11.setToolTipText("R");
        
        button.addActionListener(this);
        m11.addActionListener(this);
        m22.addActionListener(this);
        
        frame.addKeyListener(new KeyListener() {

            @Override
            public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
                //nothing
                
            }

            @Override
            public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
                int keycode = e.getKeyCode();
                switch(keycode) {
                    case KeyEvent.VK_R:
                        System.out.println("R Pressed");
                        counter = 0;    
                        button.setText("Clicks: " + counter);
                        break;
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
                //nothing
                
            }
            
        });
        
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws AWTException {
        new Clicker();
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
        if (evt.getSource()==button) {
            counter++;  
            button.setText("Clicks: " + counter);
        }
        else if (evt.getSource()==m11) {
            counter = 0;    
            button.setText("Clicks: " + counter);
        }
        else if (evt.getSource()==m22) {
            System.exit(0);
        }
        
    }

}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42660896/java-keylistener-stops-working this will help you :)

Comment: A KeyEvent is only dispatch to the component with focus. When you click on the button if now has focus so your KeyListener won't work. Don't use a KeyListener. Swing was designed to be used with Key Bindings. Read the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Key Bindings](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) for more information.

Comment: @camickr When I try to make an action for my key binding, I am getting loads of errors, and I'm pretty much copying the example word-for-word (excluding my changed action name). Is there any other way I can make it so it doesn't lose focus upon clicking the button?

Comment: @camickr Never mind, I got it working by setting the button to non-focusable. Thanks for your time.

Comment: Instead of all those questionable sources, Oracle has a good tutorial, [Creating a GUI With JFC/Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/index.html).  Skip the Netbeans section.  Anything Swing on Stack Overflow posted by @camickr will be an excellent resource.